# Solving an equation involving a GCD term.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve for $x$, given $\gcd(a + x, 3a + x - 1) = 2x + 1$, where $a$ is a positive integer. How do we go about solving such an equation?

Comment: What is your definition of GCD? Then use it!

Comment: GCD = greatest common divisor.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. What do you mean by definition of GCD?

Comment: As usual, a definition. For example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor): In mathematics, the greatest common divisor (gcd) of two or more integers, which are not all zero, is the largest positive integer that *divides* each of the integers. So in particular $2x+1\mid a+x$.

Comment: For those who want some context into where such an equation comes from, this comes from my attempts to solve Project Euler problem 443. [Project Euler problem 443](https://projecteuler.net/problem=443).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\gcd(a + x, 3a + x - 1) =\gcd(a + x, 3a + x - 1-3(a+x))=\gcd(a + x, 2x+1)$$

Comment: Euclidean algorithm and thm. of Bezout.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment please? Euclidean algorithm works when quantities are known, here there is an unknown inside the GCD term.

Comment: Thanks Robert Z., I figured the second step you wrote, now I guess I have to search for x such that $a + x = C (2x + 1)$, where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: @vamsikal Yes, you are on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align*}\gcd(a+x,3a+x-1) &= \gcd(a+x,3a+x-1-3(a+x))\\ &= \gcd(a+x,2x+1) = 2x+1.\end{align*} This means that $2x+1$ divides $a+x$, giving that $a+x = k(2x+1)$ for some positive integer $k$. Thus, $a-k = x(2k-1)$ and so $x = \dfrac{a-k}{2k-1}$. For example, if $k = 2$, then $x = \dfrac{a-2}{3}$. If $k = 3$, then $x = \dfrac{a-3}{5}$.

Thus, for all $k$ such that $a \equiv k \pmod{2k-1}$, $x = \dfrac{a-k}{2k-1}$ is a solution.