# Finding the smallest solution to a divisibility problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a positive integer $a$, can we compute the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $(2x + 1) | (a + x)$ without resorting to a linear search for $x$?

Context: This question shows up in attempting to solve [Project Euler Problem 443](https://projecteuler.net/problem=443). A related question is: [Solving an equation involving a GCD term.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348524/solving-an-equation-involving-a-gcd-term).

Since we need to find the smallest $x$ that solves this problem, I did the following: Let $C = \frac{a + x}{2x + 1}$. Start the linear-search for positive integer $x$, by starting with $C = \frac{a+1}{3}$. This helped my code go faster, but not as fast as using the solution suggested below.

Comment: Hm, I would doubt that there will be very many large values of $x$ since $2x+1$ grows faster than $a+x$ as $x$ increases.

Comment: I would like to know whether there is a way to avoid linear search. Yes, we can see that $x \leq a - 1$, but that is still too many values to search.

Comment: What have you, yourself, tried, vamsikal?  What thoughts do you have regarding another form of search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you need $a \ge 2$.

$2x+1$ is the least prime dividing $2a-1$.  This is because $2x+1 \mid a+x$ iff $2x+1 \mid 2a + 2x$ iff $2x+1 \mid 2a + 2x - (2x+1) = 2a-1$.